# Google maps KML placing all points on the equator

Tags: google-maps, kml

I've got this KML

http://www.outlawmctours.com/flickerphotofile.xml

that is loaded into this map.

http://www.outlawmctours.com/newmap.html

All of my points are loading on the equator for some reason.  In addition, Google maps only places 4 points.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your KML isn't valid.  `<Point><coordinates>-112.139167,</coordinates>
</Point>`

Comment: Thanks.  I fixed that
http://www.outlawmctours.com/flickerphotofile.xml
but it doesn't correct either.

Comment: You have lots of duplicate locations.

Answer (score 0):

Your KML isn't valid. `<Point><coordinates>-112.139167,</coordinates></Point>`

All those points will be on the equator (assuming null == 0 for a latitude).

Points with duplicate locations will overlay each other, you will only see the top marker.